# How to apply aggregation and groupby to a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called Dataprep with 19 columns and 18484 raws. I have aggregated the columns I wanted with the code below:

```
Dataprep.groupby('CustomerKey').OrderQuantity.agg('count')
```

CustomerKey is the ID number for customers and orderquantity is the number of orders by each customer. The data look like

11000  -  1

11000    -    1

11000     -   1

11000     -   1

11001 -  1

11001 -  1

11001 -  1

11001 -  1

11002 -  1

11002  - 1

11002 -  1

11002  - 1

11002  - 1

11003  - 1

11003 -  1

11003 -  1

11003 -  1

11003  - 1

11004  - 1

11004  - 1

11004 -  1

11004  - 1

First column is customerkey and other one is orderquantity.

My question is how would I apply this to the DataFrame Dataprep. I want to keep all other columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
Dataprep['new'] = Dataprep.groupby('CustomerKey').OrderQuantity.transform('count')
```

Comment: Thanks for your  quick reply. Yes I have got a new column. It is showing  11000-4, 11000-4,11000-4,11000-4,11001-4,11001-4,11001-4,11001-4, 11002-4, 11002-4,11002-4,11002-4, etc. I am looking for 11000-4,11001-4,11002-4 etc. Any way I can get that?

Comment: Then need solution in your question, transform duplicate data for new column.

Comment: When I merge Dataprep with other dataframe I got what I was looking for. Thanks for your help so far, jezreal.

Comment: Done :-) I will be trying to work out how to transform duplicate data to a new column later.